# Error: Invalid Index The given key does not identify an element in this collection value Transit gateway routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, transit-gateway

I am trying to create routes in transit gateway route table. Below is the code block.

```
locals {
  vpc_attachments_with_routes = chunklist(flatten([
    for k, v in var.vpc_attachments : setproduct([{ key = k }], v["tgw_route"]) if length(lookup(v, "tgw_route", {})) > 0
  ]), 2)
  }

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table" "route" {
  count = var.create_tgw ? 1 : 0
  transit_gateway_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway.this[0].id
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route" "this" {
  count = length(local.vpc_attachments_with_routes)

  destination_cidr_block = local.vpc_attachments_with_routes[count.index][1]["destination_cidr_block"]
  blackhole              = lookup(local.vpc_attachments_with_routes[count.index][1], "blackhole", null)

  transit_gateway_route_table_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.route[count.index].id
  transit_gateway_attachment_id  = tobool(lookup(local.vpc_attachments_with_routes[count.index][1], "blackhole", false)) == false ? aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.this[local.vpc_attachments_with_routes[count.index][0]["key"]].id : null
   depends_on = [
    aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.route,
  ]
}
```

Error:

Error: Invalid index\n\n  on ../modules/tgw/main.tf line 85, in resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route" "this":\n  85:   transit_gateway_route_table_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.route[count.index].id\n    |----------------\n    | aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.route is tuple with 1 element\n    | count.index is 1\n\nThe given key does not identify an element in this collection value.\n\n",

Comment: What are the values of your variables? create_tgw, vpc_attachments and others.

Comment: How did it go? The error still persists?

Comment: Yes, as I said, it will come if create_tgw is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have only 0 or 1 `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.route`, depending on the value of `create_tgw`. So it should be:

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route" "this" {
  count = length(local.vpc_attachments_with_routes)

  destination_cidr_block = local.vpc_attachments_with_routes[count.index][1]["destination_cidr_block"]
  blackhole              = lookup(local.vpc_attachments_with_routes[count.index][1], "blackhole", null)

  transit_gateway_route_table_id = var.create_tgw ? aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.route[0].id : null 

  transit_gateway_attachment_id  = tobool(lookup(local.vpc_attachments_with_routes[count.index][1], "blackhole", false)) == false ? aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.this[local.vpc_attachments_with_routes[count.index][0]["key"]].id : null
}
```

Comment: This says "Invalid expression resource \"aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route\" \"this\":\n  89:   depends_on = \u001b[4mvar.create_tgw\u001b[0m ? aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.route[0].id : [] A static list expression is required.\n\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n","

Comment: @MayaRay Depends on is not needed, and can be removed.

Comment: It gives this error:
Error: Missing required argument in resource \"aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route\" \"this\":\n  85:   transit_gateway_route_table_id = var.create_tgw ? aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.route[0].id : null \n\nThe argument \"transit_gateway_route_table_id\" is required, but no definition\nwas found

Comment: If your `create_tgw` is false you will not have `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route` as I exlaiend in the answer.

Comment: I am trying to share one transit gateway through multiple accounts, if I mark create_tgw as true for all, it will create transit gateway, attachments, routes everything in both the accounts. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @MayaRay Your new design issue would be better asked as a new question with all the relevant details. In your current question, the error that you posted has been hopefully addressed.